# Scroll to the selected element in a react listview

Tags: reactjs

I have not managed to make this work. I render my list of items and the item that is currently selected gets a "ref" property.

```
class CityListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { selected, id, name } = this.props
    return <div ref={selected && "selected" } style={{padding:10,borderBottom:"1px solid lightgray",fontWeight:selected && "bold"}}>{name}</div>
  }
}

class Cities extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.selected && this.refs.selected.scrollIntoView()
  }

  listItem(item) {
    const selected = item.id == this.props.selected
    return <CityListItem key={item.id} {...item} selected={selected}/>
  }

  render() {
    const { cities, selected } = this.props
    return <div>
      <List items={cities} renderer={this.listItem.bind(this)}/>
    </div>
  }
}
```

It gives me the error that simple components cannot have `ref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React only allows refs on react components. In your case `<Cities>`, `<CistyListItem>` or `<List>`.  So a ref on a `<div>` is not allowed.

The simple solution could be to move the `ref=...` statement to the render of CityListItem, like:

```
return <CityListItem 
  ref={selected && "selected" } 
  key={item.id} {...item} 
  selected={selected}/>
```

Maybe this will work.